# Some polygons on few devices disappeared

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, rendering, render, polygon

I released Android game and some players report a rendering issue.
Some polygons of my 3d objects are missing and black squares are visible.
Note, squares are not visible instead of missing parts of models.

It could be reproduced only few devices. The only general thing I find - all the users with the problem have Xiaomi.

I have no clue what could cause the problem.

Please, see screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd11o.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxNE4.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zoez.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBvEM.png

Answer (score 0):

I finally fix the issue.
The problem was caused by the driver issue on some Android devices (with Adreno GPU) if GPU instancing is enabled for material.